# displaying text box in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create an input box for one of my windows in pygame. I have created the class for it but when I tried to display the input box it gave me an error.
Here is the code for the input box:

```
class inp_box:
def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, width, height, text = ""):
  self.rect = pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, width, height)
  self.colour = [200, 200, 200]
  self.text = text
  self.text_surf = FONT.render(text , True, self.colour)
  self.current = False
  self.colourAc = False
  
def enter_text(self, event):
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            self.colourAc = not self.colourAc
        else:
            self.colourAc = False

        if self.colourAc:
            self.color = [150, 150, 150]
        else:
            self.color = [200, 200, 200]

    if event.type == pygame.K_KEYDOWN:
        if self.colourAc:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                print(self.text)
                self.text = ""
            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                self.text = self.text[:-1]
            else:
                self.text += event.unicode

            self.text_surf = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.colour)

def Updtext(self):
    widt = max(200, self.text_surf.get_width() + 10)
    self.rect.width = widt

def showBox(self, display):
    display.blit(self.text_surf, (self.rect.xpos + 5, self.rect.ypos + 5))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, self.colour, self.rect)
```

This is part of the main loop where the input box would be displayed:

```
elif set_wind.checkUp():
    main_wind_but = return_but.hover(mouse_pos, mouse_click)
    return_but.showBut(set_wind.reTitle())
    enter_wind_but = enter_but.hover(mouse_pos, mouse_click)
    enter_but.showBut(set_wind.reTitle())
    title1_box.showBut(set_wind.reTitle())
    desc1_box.showBut(set_wind.reTitle())
    input_box.showBox(set_wind)

    if main_wind_but:
        Main = main_wind.setCurrent()
        set_wind.endCurrent()
```

This is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 282, in <module>
input_box.showBox(set_wind)
File "main.py", line 128, in showBox
display.blit(self.text_surf, (self.rect.xpos + 5, self.rect.ypos + 5))
AttributeError: 'window' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

I've tried to find solutions to this problem but none of them seem to answer my problem.
I appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: `set_wind` is not the display surface. What is it?

Comment: It's the setup window. (set-up account details). I created a window class and updating the current display as I'm unable to run multiple windows in pygame (based on research).

Comment: `blit` is a method of `pygame.Surface`. You cannot `blit` somthing on the setup window. No way.

Comment: I managed to blit buttons on each of the "windows" and they work fine. I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this online
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+make+a+text+input+box+python+pygame

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
COLOR_INACTIVE = pg.Color('lightskyblue3')
COLOR_ACTIVE = pg.Color('dodgerblue2')
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 32)


class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = COLOR_INACTIVE
        self.text = text
        self.txt_surface = FONT.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False
            # Change the current color of the input box.
            self.color = COLOR_ACTIVE if self.active else COLOR_INACTIVE
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.text)
                    self.text = ''
                elif event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                # Re-render the text.
                self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)

    def update(self):
        # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width = max(200, self.txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        self.rect.w = width

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+5))
        # Blit the rect.
        pg.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)



def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    input_box1 = InputBox(100, 100, 140, 32)
    input_box2 = InputBox(100, 300, 140, 32)
    input_boxes = [input_box1, input_box2]
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        for box in input_boxes:
            box.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I used this to help me create the input box. I'm not sure on how to get it to display as that's the issue.

Comment: Can you show the whole code, from the time you import pygame

Comment: I copied the code onto a pdf document as I'm not sure if I can put code in comments.file:///C:/Users/siwss/Downloads/code.pdf

Comment: Convert the pdf to jpg

Comment: You'll may need to request access because this is in google drive.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1evQgy6ZQZwO4VR4m7m8KDs0Q8bA6Zesb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll look into it.

Comment: ok, I think I solved it. Pls try `input_box.showBox(set_wind.screen)`  to put in line 282 and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Great! Please accept this answer to close this question. Thanks!